# Setting column style in FlexTable

Tags: gwt

I'm new to GWT and trying to understand it, but have encountered with a problem. When I try to add column style to the specified column in the table

```
table.getColumnFormatter().addStyleName(column, "columnStyle");
```

it doesn't take effect, but when I apply this style to each cell in the column

```
table.getCellFormatter().addStyleName(row, column, "columnStyle");
```

it works fine. Why I can not apply the style to the whole column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible that you're adding unsupported CSS elements to `<col>`, it only accepts backgrounds, width and borders CSS properties, whereas a `<td>` can accept many more.